# How to put the product price with a ManyToManyField between Sellers and Products Table

Tags: django

I want a product price between two table Sellers and Products.

Here are my models-

```
class Products(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    price= models.IntegerField(default=0)
    category= models.ForeignKey(Category,on_delete=models.CASCADE,default=1 )
    description= models.TextField(blank=True, null= True)
    image= models.ImageField(upload_to='uploads/products/')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name



class Sellers(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    products = models.ManyToManyField(Products)
    description= models.TextField(blank=True, null= True)
    image= models.ImageField(upload_to='uploads/sellers/')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Where to put the product price for each seller?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would create a new class Price and store the seller's prices there:

```
class Price(models.Model):
     seller = models.ForeignKey(Seller,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
     product = models.ForeignKey(Product,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
     price = models.IntegerField()
```

You should consider to create a uniqueness constraint to avoid multiple product price for one product seller combination

**Update**: If you like to have the additional fields in the same table as the manytomany relationships check out the answer of Willem Van Onsem who proposed the usage of the *through* option. See [Django Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#intermediary-manytomany)

Answer (score 2):

You can define this in the [*junction table* <sup>[wiki]</sup>](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junction_table) of the `ManyToManyField` by specifying a [**`through=…`** model <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through):

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    price = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category,on_delete=models.CASCADE,default=1 )
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null= True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='uploads/products/')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Seller(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    products = models.ManyToManyField(
        Product,
        through='SellerProduct'
    )
    description= models.TextField(blank=True, null= True)
    image= models.ImageField(upload_to='uploads/sellers/')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class SellerProduct(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    seller = models.ForeignKey(Seller, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    price = models.IntegerField()
```

Comment: This is a good addition to my answer! I did not know about the 'through' option, its great if you want to have the additional fields inside the manytomany table. Will vote this answer up and add a comment to mine.